# How can we write sql query instead of parameters in substring function in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Suppose this is our normal substring function

```
select substring("Hello World",1,3); //SUBSTRING(string, start, length)
```

output is "Hel"

But I want to run the query where instead of number parameters I want to write the query itself

```
text="Hello world, user:[XYZ] here"
```

I want to extract `XYZ` i.e. name in text for every row in a table and I don't know its position.
the only thing we know is after the `user:` our username is present.

```
select substring(text,
select position("user:[" in text)+5 from ABC,
select position("]" in text)-position("user:[" in text)-6 from ABC
) from ABC;
```

Comment: If you're using MySQL 8.x you can use the `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` function to extract based on a regular expression pattern.

Comment: If not, I think your query looks about right.

Comment: try `SUBSTRING_INDEX` with `SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('Hello world, user:[XYZ] here', 'user:[', -1), ']', 1)`

Comment: @ProGu if there are more than one users how can we find that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to extract the username from the text.

**Example:**

> ```
> select *
> , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`text`, 'user:[', -1), ']', 1) AS `user`
> from ABC
> where `text` like '%user:[%]%'
> ```

| text | user |
| --- | --- |
| Hello world, user:[XYZ] here | XYZ |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=296e3676d1a8a7f117eddfd45a00d7c5)*

Comment: If there are more than one users how can we find that?